# Google Cloud Storage - Invalid bucket name (PHP)

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I tried to upload a file on root in my Google cloud Storage by doing this:

```
$bucketName = "bucket-name.appspot.com";
        $objectName = $client_id . '_' . rand(0, 200) . '_' . $type . '.pdf';
        $storage = new StorageClient();
        $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
        $object = $bucket->upload($datas, [
            'name' => $objectName
        ]);
```

This worked and i successfully upload a `file($datas)`.

Now i created a folder in my root storage and called it `"contracts"`. So my `$bucketName` is updated to include the folder like this:

```
$bucketName = "bucket-name.appspot.com/contracts";
        $objectName = $client_id . '_' . rand(0, 200) . '_' . $type . '.pdf';
        $storage = new StorageClient();
        $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
        $object = $bucket->upload($datas, [
            'name' => $objectName
        ]);
```

As you can see this is now updated to: `$bucketName = "bucket-name.appspot.com/contracts";`. But this gives me this error now:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid bucket name: 'bucket-name.appspot.com/contracts'"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid bucket name: 'bucket-name.appspot.com/contracts'"
 }
}
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See:

- http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-storage/latest/storage/storageclient?method=bucket
- http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-storage/latest/storage/bucket?method=upload

You should add `/contracts/` to `$objectName`.

```
$bucketName = "bucket-name.appspot.com";
$objectName = '/contracts/' . $client_id . '_' . rand(0, 200) . '_' . $type . '.pdf';
$storage = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$object = $bucket->upload($datas, [
    'name' => $objectName
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Withing Google Cloud Storage, there are only `buckets` and `objects`.  The notion of folders is only an *illusion*.   For example, a file that you wish to access as `gs://yourbucket/yourfolder/yourfile` is bucket `yourbucket` and file (object) `yourfolder/yourfile`.

There is a dedicated article on this story at [How Subdirectories work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork).